# fade in and fade out random with jquery

Tags: jquery, random, fade

Recently i was asked to do this effect

http://mobile.bebitalia.com/home.do

but it is made with scriptaculus and i need somehow to achieve it using jquery.

i found this example but it is the half way

http://jsfiddle.net/5rkEw/

Can you help me out to do the fade out effect after  the fade in completes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm in the middle of putting together a fiddle but you can try this using similiar markup as the example you gave

```
// Translated from scriptaculus
// http://mobile.bebitalia.com/home.do

function hideCube() {
$('#gctu1w_bg').show('slow');
$('.cube').each(function(index, element) {
    var sleepTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000);
    var t = setTimeout(function() {
        var d = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000);
        $(element).fadeTo(d, 0);
    }, sleepTime);
});
}

$(function() {

$('.cube').each(function(index, element) {
    var sleepTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000);
    var t = setTimeout(function() {
        var d = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
        $(element).fadeTo(d, 0.99);
    }, sleepTime);
});

var h = setTimeout(hideCube, 4000);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nickywaites/GBhMw/

Comment: @Nicky, you just copied and pasted that from the site. there was not much work on your part. and you did not give credit where credit is due..

Comment: although you used jquery instead of scriptalicious, but aside from that a carbon copy..

Comment: It works great. I didn't feel comfortable to make the transfer from scriptaculus to jquery. I will read your code and try to learn something

Comment: You're welcome dianikol.  Neal I think I answered his question but I appreciate your concerns so I've updated my response if it wasn't clear I was referring to his example he gave in the question.  This one uses anonymous functions and will work against any number of cubes so I think it is different enough.

Comment: As far i understand Nicky setTime with appropriate times is really good with jquery for making sequential animations

Comment: jQuery is really great for manipulating the DOM which is really all this is doing but with random timings.  If you're interested I've been working on a plugin but it is still has a few rough edges.  http://jsfiddle.net/nickywaites/dBPdh/

Comment: Cool Nicky!! I'm not ready yet to do something like that. Just simple tasks with ajax and simple animations. Can you provide me any good resources?  One quick question. Why the above example doesnt work with fadeIn(d)?  Only with the fadeTo(d,1).

Comment: this is  my msn if  you want to talk about these stuff. dianikol85@yahoo.gr

Comment: I'll send you an email dianikol.

Comment: Also its good practice on stackoverflow to mark answers as accepted if they've answered your question.  If not then let me know so I can update this.

Answer (score 1):

here is a good solution:

```
fadeInout = {
    init: function() {
        v = $("#blocks > li").css('visibility', 'hidden'),
        cur = 0,
        rem = 0;
        for (var j, x, i = v.length; i; 
             j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = v[--i], v[i] = v[j], v[j] = x);
        //other startup code
        return this;
    },

    fades: function() {
        this.fadein();
    },
    fadein: function() {
        v.eq(cur++).css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn();
        if (cur != v.length) setTimeout(fadeInout.fadein, 50);
        else setTimeout(fadeInout.fadeout, 100);
    },
    fadeout: function() {
        v.eq(rem++).css('visibility', 'none').fadeOut().show();
        if (rem != v.length) setTimeout(fadeInout.fadeout, 50);
    }

}

fadeInout.init().fades();
```

and here is the fiddle that shows it: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/rcts4/

Comment: the fade out seems quite buggy. it fades out the last li instead of a random one. if you put less speed you will notice it :)

Comment: @dianikol, never said it was perfect, but it is a start :-)  you can try rerandomizing the divs before calling fadeout and see if that helps